# Swift 3: Array Value for key

Tags: ios, swift

New to swift, just trying to catch some data.

so here is my swift code i used

```
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "kurdiebg", withExtension: "plist")!
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let dataArray = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[String:String]]

        // Bloody Error is this
        let request = dataArray(value(forKey: "Key"))

        print(dataArray.count)
    } catch {
        print("This error must not happen", error)

    }
```

i am getting

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[[String : String]]'

what exactly i am trying to do?
so i have this [plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEWqE.png) and i want to allow users to search in it , i perform this via a button action with this code above, so if a user write abbey, it would get the **kurdi** meaning,

Comment: `dataArray.value(forKey: "Key")`

Comment: Hi rmaddy, tried this, it gets me **Value of type '[[String : String]]' has no member 'value'**

Comment: Right. That's from key-value coding and exists on `NSArray`, not a Swift array. You have an array of dictionaries. What are you actually trying to get out of the array?

Comment: Hi rmaddy, it's a plist file with an array of dictionaries, so for example i want to get the value of **FishName** when users types shark, that code is used on a button action

Comment: It would help if you update your question with an excerpt of your plist data and clearly show an example of what you are trying to get from it.

Comment: @rmaddy,updated

Comment: Why do you have an array of dictionaries where each dictionary only has the two key/value pairs? Do you plan to support other languages? If you only need to support the two languages, it would be a lot simpler to have a no array and just a single dictionary where each key is the English word and its value is the Kurdi translation.

Comment: @rmaddy, planning to do something like that, supporting other languages, do you have a solution with this ?

Comment: @rmaddy , may i know your way? the easy way you call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are using wrong syntax.

`dataArray` is not a function, you probably mean

```
dataArray.value(forKey: "Key")
```

However using KVC methods like `value(forKey` is only useful if you know what KVC is and why you need KVC. In this case it's inappropriate.

---

`dataArray` – as the name implies – is an array which is subscripted by **index** so you can get for example the value for key `english` of the first item with

```
dataArray[0]["english"]
```

which is a synonym for

```
dataArray[0].object(forKey:"english")
```

Or if you want to find an item for a specific key

```
dataArray.first(where: { $0["english"] == "abbey"})
```